# What model should I take for fluid flow with bubbles, in pipe?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

We try to combine model with experiment(already done).
What model should we take do draw thermomap of pipe? What laboratory can we ask?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modeling fluid flow in pipes with entrained bubbles is dealt with in the engineering fluid dynamics arena called *two-phase flow*. A search on this topic should furnish some useful guidance.